# Groups of order $2\cdot 31\cdot 61$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What are all groups (up to isomorphism) of order $2\cdot 31\cdot 61$?

Letting $n_p$ be the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of such a group, $G$, you can show $n_{31}=1$ using the Sylow theorems ($n_{31}\equiv 1$ (mod $31$), and $n_{31}$ divides $2\cdot 61$, then use brute force). So, $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of size $31$. **Assuming $G$ also has a subgroup $H$ of size $2\cdot 61=122$**, we would have that 
$$
G = N\rtimes_\varphi H
$$
where $\varphi:H\to \text{Aut}(N)\cong \mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism. There are only two possible groups of size $122$ for $H$, the cyclic one and $D_{61}$. Each admits a nontrivial $\varphi$, as follows. For $H=C_{122}=C_2\times C_{61}$, $(0,n)$ maps to the identity automorphism, and $(1,n)$ maps to inversion. In $D_{61}$, rotations map to trivial automorphisms, and reflections to inversion.

If my **assumption** was correct, there are four possibilities for $G$:
$$
\mathbb{Z}/(3782\mathbb{Z}),\qquad
 \mathbb{Z}/(31\mathbb{Z})\times D_{61},\qquad
\mathbb{Z}/(31\mathbb{Z})\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb{Z}/(122\mathbb{Z})\qquad
\mathbb{Z}/(31\mathbb{Z})\rtimes_\varphi D_{61}
$$
My question is, was my assumption correct? If so, how can you prove this, and if not, what groups did I miss?

**Edit:** A presentation for the last group, the nontrivial semidirect product with $D_{61}$, is 
$$
\langle a,r,s\,|\,a^{31}=1,r^{61}=1,s^2=1,srs=r^{-1},sas=a^{-1}, ra=ar\rangle
$$
The nontrivial semidirect product with $\mathbb{Z}/(122\mathbb{Z})$ is actually $(\mathbb{Z}/61\mathbb{Z})\times D_{31}$.

Comment: There are four groups. I think you have missed $C_{61} \times D_{31}$. In your presentation, you can have $srs=r^{\pm 1}$ and $sas = a^{\pm 1}$, which gives the four non-isomorphic possibilities.

Comment: Ohhh I see. There actually is a nontrivial semidirect product of $C_{31}$ and $C_{122}$, and this is precisely $C_{61}\times D_{31}$. I will edit to include this possibility, but I still wonder how to prove there are no others.

Comment: BTW, your presentation is missing the relation $ar=ra$. By Sylow's Theorem, there are unique and therefore normal Sylow $31$- and $61$-subgroups $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle r \rangle$. Now if we let $s$ be any element of order $2$, you get just the four possibilities for $sas$ and $srs$, each of which gives a complete presentation, so there are exactly $4$ groups altogether.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Sylow's theorem alone does not imply uniqueness of a Sylow $61$-subgroup, as $2 \cdot 31 \equiv 1 \pmod {61}$ - a little more is needed

Comment: Thank, the missing relation has been added. I agree with zcn, it is not so obvious why $n_{61}=1$.

Comment: Well OK, maybe a tiny bit more is needed! Any group of twice odd order has a normal subgroup $N$ of index $2$, and you can apply Sylow's Theorem to that to deduce that $N$ has a normal Sylow $31$-subgroup, which must also be normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is a group of order $2n$, with $n$ odd, then $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$ (consider the regular representation of $G$). In this case every group of order $31 \cdot 61$ is cyclic, so $G$ does have a subgroup of order $2 \cdot 61 = 122$ (since the Sylow $61$-subgroup of $G$ is characteristic in the subgroup of index $2$, hence normal in $G$). Then the rest of your reasoning applies to show that there are exactly $4$ such groups $G$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: Is there a short explanation you can give for what you mean in you parenthetical expression, i.e., what you mean by the word "characteristic" in the phrase the $61$-subgroup is _characteristic_ in the subgroup of index 2? Or perhaps a wikipedia link?

Comment: Here's the definition: [characteristic subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup). The relevant fact is: if $H$ is characteristic in $K$ and $K \unlhd G$, then $H \unlhd G$

Comment: By the way, in this particular case, one can show there is a subgroup of index $2$ directly, since the Sylow $31$-subgroup is normal. The general fact about groups of order $2 \cdot $ odd is useful though